# What is the exhaustive list of guidelines/practices/rules to fully conform with functional paradigm?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, paradigms

I've started playing around with Kotlin, but I sense my own limitation in the way I program. My problem is that I still think Java therefore the style is still imperative, my question is to all functional programming zealots , which I believe would be very useful to all people who at the very beginning stage and also need to 'brake' their brain to start building it again; to leave comfort zone and start thinking pseudo and not in "whatever is your first language". I believe it is possible for highly experienced polyglot developers to chew the concepts down to **plain advices of what makes your program being written in entirely functional way and what violates the paradigm**. I don't know all the quirks but please don't hesitate to include universally accepted terms which might be unknown to me(I can always lookup). At this point I need this set of rules to make myself suffer at first and not break them but then I know I will feel it, analyze guidelines and understand how they are worse/better which of course is my own homework.

So example of these guidelines, would be something like:

- Never change state, this can be avoided by using x, y, z
- Operate using higher order functions only (I maybe wrong, just example)

I hope the answer will give me long term reference to put myself in extreme conditions where I stop escaping to OOP whenever I feel uncomfortable. And now when I look at Kotlin I understand how I've should've been thinking about problems, it is about intention not about the structure imposed by one language or another. Intention can always be converted to a language of your choice and backed up by design patterns applicable to the language, but to find that middle ground I need to jail myself first from the comfort zone.

Comment: A) Never mutate any variables but only create new variables B) factor out repetitive code in (possibly higher-order) helper functions C) find what names and structure those helpers have in the standard library and learn to use those instead of your own

Comment: There is no exact definition for FP, but I want to leave some advice: Try to solve a well known problem, and impose restrictions upon yourself. "Never change state" is a good start. Other ideas: no loops; avoid statements and prefer expressions; strict separation of data and logic; handle errors without using exceptions; build a program just by composing functions; try to have just one place that does I/O and keep the rest "pure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Avoid mutable state like the plague**.

  One of the main points of using functional programming, possibly the main one, is to avoid all the little pitfalls, bugs, issues one needs to deal with when using mutable state. You should do everything you can in order to avoid mutating state. For instance, instead of using C-style `for`-loops where you need to keep a counter variable updated, use `map` and other higher-order functions in order to abstract away your iteration patterns. This also means that you should never change the value of a variable if you can avoid that. Instead, you should be defining almost all of your variables, preferrably all of them, as constants, and using functions to compute new values from them instead of mutating them.
- **Avoid side-effects like the plague**.

  Mutable state's ugly cousin, side-effects. Side effects mean anything other than taking a value and returning a value in a function. If that function prints data, mutates global variables, sends messages to threads, or anything, anything other than simply taking its parameters, computing a value from them, and returning a value, that function has side-effects. Side-effects are important (see next bullet point), but if you use them a lot, they get impossible to track. Just think of how everyone tells you to avoid global variables in imperative programming. Functional programming goes a step further and tries to avoid all side-effects. The bulk of your program should be made of *pure functions*. (See ahead)
- **When you need to use side-effects, keep them contained.**

  Yes, I just told you to run away from side-effects. However, no program is useful without side-effects of some kind. Graphical User Interface? Side-effect. Audio output? Side-effect. Printing to a shell? Side-effect. So you can't really get rid of side-effects if you want to build useful stuff. 
  What you should do instead is write your code so that all your side-effecting code lives in a thin layer which mostly calls pure functions and then does the required side-effects using the result of these pure function calls.
- **Use pure functions for everything you can**.

  This is sort of the flipside of the previous point. A *pure function* is a function which has no side-effects and does not mutate anything. It can only take in parameters and return a value. You should use these *a lot*. For instance, instead of doing your logging within functions which are computing stuff, you should be constructing your log strings using pure functions, and then letting your side-effects layer call these pure functions, call more pure functions in order to format the log strings into a full log, and then output the log itself from your side-effects layer.
- **Use higher-order functions to structure your code**.

  Higher-order functions are, in a way, the glue that makes functional programming work. A higher-order function is a function which takes one or more functions as parameters and/or returns a function. The power of higher-order functions is that they can encapsulate many of the patterns which you would use in an imperative-style program in a declarative manner. For instance, let's take a look at the three most common higher-order functions:

  `map` is a function which takes a function and a list of values, applies its function argument to each of those values, and returns a new list with the results. `map` encapsulates the whole pattern of iterating over a list doing an operation on each value in a declarative manner.

  `filter` is a function which takes a function which returns a boolean and a list of values, applies its function argument to each of those values and returns a list containing only those values for which its function argument returns `true`. It encapsulates the whole pattern of selecting results from a list in a declarative manner.

  `reduce`, also known as `fold`, takes an initial value, a binary function and a list of values. It uses its function argument to combine the initial value with the first value of the list, then combines the result with the next value of the list and keeps on doing this until it has reduced the list to just one single value. It encapsulates the entire pattern of obtaining an aggregate value from a list of values.

  This is in no way an exhaustive list of higher-order functions, but these three are the most common ones. I hope this has been enough to show how you can structure code which would require a lot of tracking variables using only functions in a declarative manner. If you use these higher-order functions well, it's likely you won't ever need a `for` or `while` loop again.

This is definitely *not*  an **exhaustive** list of functional programming practices, but I think most functional programmers would agree these five guidelines form the core of what functional programming is about. If you want to really learn how to apply these, my advice would be to learn a *pure* functional programming language such as Haskell, so you are forced to abandon the imperative paradigm and to learn how to structure things functionally instead. I would recommend the fantastic [Haskell Programming from First Principles](http://haskellbook.com/) as a starting resource if you choose to go this way. In case you don't want to/can't put down the cash, [Brent Yorgey's Haskell course at UPenn](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/) is also a great free resource.